# Uncomputability of least member selection

Tags: computability

I want to show that there is no TM $f$ such that whenever $W_x$ is nonempty then $f(x)$ is defined and is the least member of $W_x$, Where $W_x=\{w:w \in \Sigma^{*}\text{ and } M_x \text{ on }w \text{ Halts}\}$

Usually when I want to show that such a problem is not member of RE, I use Rice's theorem, diagonalization, the recursion theorem, or I show that if such a problem is computable then $\overline{HP}$ is computable. But I think I did not fully understand this question. *(Edit: Before i read comments i did not know what is the definition of $W_x$)*

Comment: If $W_x$ is not defined in the problem statement, it's probably in the index or list of symbols, if the book has those. Have you checked there?

Comment: The set $W_x$ consists of all inputs on which the Turing machine encoded by $x$ halts.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Then the problem is finding the least input s.t TM $M_x$ halts on that input is uncomputable ?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus $W_x = \{w | M_x\text{ on } w \text{ Halts} \}$ ?

Comment: The problem is to show that there is no Turing machine $M$ such that if $W_x \neq \emptyset$, then $M$ halts on $x$ and returns $\min W_x$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Then we can build a TM $T$ s.t for every input $x \geq 2$ accept and for $x=1$ simmulate $M$ on $w$ if it halts accept. Hence if $f(T)=1$ then $\langle M,w \rangle \in HP$ otherwise $\langle M,w \rangle \notin HP$ , am i right ?

Comment: Right, that's one way of solving this.

Comment: @OmidYaghoubi, add that as an answer to your own question (and edit to clarify what $W_x$ is).

Comment: @vonbrand Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments, The problem is:

> Show that there is no Turing machine $M_f$ such that if $W_x \neq \emptyset$, then $M_f$ halts on $x$ and returns $\min W_x$

To solve this, We assume $f \in RE$ then we show $HP\in R$ which is a contradiction.

Now we build a TM $HP_{TM}$ such that $HP_{TM}(\langle M,w \rangle)=1 \Leftrightarrow M \text{ halts on }w$ and we use $M_f$ to build that.

$HP_{TM}(\langle M,w\rangle) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\text{1- Build a new machine }T (x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\text{If }(x\geq2)\text{ then ACCEPT}\\
\text{If }(x=1)\text{ then do:}\\
\hspace{14pt} \text{1- Simulate }M\text{ on input }w\\
\hspace{14pt} \text{2- ACCEPT}\\
\end{array}\\
\right.\\
\text{2- Compute }M_f(T)\\
\text{3- If }M_f(T)=1\text{ then ACCEPT}\\
\text{4- Otherwise REJECT}
\end{array}\right.$

Clearly we can build a TM $T$ in finite amount of time in Stage 1. Observe that $W_t \neq \emptyset$ and $1 \in W_t \Leftrightarrow \langle M,w\rangle \in HP$ hence $HP_{TM}$ decides $HP$ therefore $HP \in R$. We know $HP \notin R$ so this is a contradiction and we can conclude $f\notin RE$.

$\blacksquare$